# How can I pause the execution of vba code when error?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I wish to pause the execution of my **VBA** code once an error appears, and continue the execution when corrected?! Because I have a very long execution, so it always goes from the beginning...

Comment: If it errors, it will have to start over unless you add error handling that uses the Resume statement (not recommended unless you really know what you're doing)

Comment: in fact it is only getting data from diffrent excel workbooks, so when it does not find one I wish it can pause in there, and once i correct it, it starts from the last unsaved row

Comment: then you should add error handling that allows it to skip this so you don't even have to correct it :)

Comment: Kind of ugly, but you could do this, by adding some kind of flag to a row, if you are done reading the data you needed. If your code crashes, you can restart it, at the last row, that was flagged.

Comment: yeah i thought bout it and it is ugly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use an error handler.  Something like

```
On Error GoTo errorTrap
```

at the beginning of your code directly after your dims and other setup.
Then for the actual errortrap you would write this before the End Sub.

The whole thing would look like this.

```
Sub test()
  Dim v As Variant, x As Integer 'etc etc
  On Error GoTo errorTrap
  'run your code here.  An example is below
  x = "hello" 'this will create an error since hello is not an integer
  MsgBox "finished"

  End 'ignore the error trap when done
errorTrap:
  Debug.Print Err.Description
  Stop 'stop here and figure out what is going on.
  'any other code needed to fix the error
  Resume Next
End Sub
```